# How to use Array#sample(n, random: rng) syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, random, ruby-1.9.3

The documentation for [`Array#sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) says it can take an `rng`:

> If rng is given, it will be used as the random number generator.

How can a range function as a random number generator, or why is such thing useful?

Also the hash form suggests there are other options, but I can't find anything about them. Trying out `[1,2,3,4,5].sample(3)` behaves just like `[1,2,3,4,5].sample(3, random: 1..2)`.

Comment: I'd guess you can use the random number generator can be used as an additional source for random numbers (like a hardware device) that may provide a better entropy than Ruby's built-in RNG.

Comment: "A random number generator (RNG) is a computational or physical device designed to generate a sequence of numbers or symbols that lack any pattern, i.e. appear random." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: I am having the same confusion... I am still not understood, what is the purpose of the second optional argument with `#sample` method. If you are well now, would you tell me, the use-case of this scenario ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit As Koraktor said, or if you want to use your own, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument should be a random number generator (RNG).

If one is not provided, it defaults to the "stock" Ruby implementation.

It can be replaced with an arbitrary RNG, like one that isn't at all random:

```
class NotAtAllRandom
  def self.rand(x=0)
    0
  end  
end  

> (1..10000).sample(3, random: NotAtAllRandom)
=> [1, 2, 3]
> (1..10000).sample(3, random: NotAtAllRandom)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Misread rng for range instead of random number generator, tried it out, didn't make sense. You cleared it up, thanks.

Comment: @steenslag I guess it does kind of look like range--duh; didn't even see that.

Comment: "I'm not clear on why you think it's a range.": `'range'.tr('aeiou', '') == 'rng'`.

Comment: @muistooshort My interpreter was broken.